# How to smoothen a cubic bezier transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm using the following css transition:

```
cubic-bezier(0.16, 1, 0.29, 0.99)
```

The issue is that at the end of the animation, the velocity of the element is so slow that the human eye can see the individual frames.

Here is a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/vivmaha/xu7dzrbs/

Is there a common solution for the above problem?

For example, can I specify both a cubic bezier AND a minimum velocity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the apparent slowness (i.e. as it is sometimes referred to as **[jank](http://jankfree.org/)**) at the end of an animation depends on what CSS attribute you are animating.

For example, if it is `left` attribute being animated then the *jank*-iness will be pretty obvious but if it is replaced by something that **[animates `translateX` on a `transform` property](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)** then I think the result will be much smoother.

I believe **[CSS Triggers](http://csstriggers.com/)** is a good resource regarding this, in that it tells you which properties trigger *layout*, *paint* and finally *composition*.

Other than that, you probably need to present us with a demo depicting the slowness. So that we could better tell if it is something to do with easing curves or if it is a problem with the property you are animating in the first place.

Here is a [before](http://jsfiddle.net/vivmaha/u11wqjvk/2/) and [after](http://jsfiddle.net/vivmaha/xu7dzrbs/) of this solution.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks for the CSS Triggers link as well, I will be using it in the future. I've edited your answer with jsfiddles for folks to compare the before and after.