# Little "Jump" on the end of css Animation

Tags: css-animations, gsap

This is a rather general Question. Using css animations or TweenMax, some Browsers seem to re-render some elements at the end of the animation, so there is a little "jump" of pixels to be seen. On some browsers it looks massive, on some you hardly notice. The smaller the image, the more obvious it becomes. Does anyone has experienced such a behaviour? And knows a bugfix? Help is very appreciated!

Comment: imho, could be a number of reasons for that e.g. either because of the [property that was animated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291734/how-to-smoothen-a-cubic-bezier-transition/33299293#33299293) always lands in absolute pixels and not in-between or [because of hardware acceleration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882563/greensock-tweenlite-transformations/33885174#33885174) (or the lack of it, depends on situations) making the animation to first uploaded to GPU and then finally when the animation settles down, off-loaded from it and looks sharp again, hence the apparent jump.

Comment: I'm not aware of any bugs like that at all, at least in GSAP. It'd be very helpful to see a codepen (or jsfiddle) example so that we can identify what's going on with your code, what properties you're animating, what might be interfering, etc.

Comment: There are webkit bugs that will relate to 3D transforms (mainly because of z-axis). This causes the element to have anti-alias on the element while animating due to hardware acceleration. And then the element will become sharp after the element completes the animation. Which could be that jump your seeing? This usually happens with elements that have text, images, or use background-images. This is a webkit bug with 3d transforms due to the z-axis. It can be fixed or a workaround, but it depends on what how and what your animating. So provide a code example to see if this is causing that.

Comment: Tween.js and TweenMax both have this problem. See these links: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/14874-long-animations-jumping-at-the-startend-when-using-easing/ and https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/issues/116